# В Аризоне. В Мичигане. На Аляске

Tags: предлоги

Почему из всех американских штатов только Аляска требует предлог "на"?

Comment: It's also *на Гавайях* and *на Род-Айленде*.

Comment: Аляска — полуостров. Вот и разгадка

Comment: @Shady_arc: Florida and Michigan are too, but it's *во Флориде* and *в Мичигане* (when speaking of the states). *На Мичигане* would mean "on the Lake Michigan".

Comment: There are no specific rules. You just remember it.

Answer (score 7):

Скорее всего, потому что Аляска воспринимается не только как штат (административное деление), но и как географическая область, Розенталь говорит о "горных областях": на Урале, на Балканах.

Answer (score 1):

As Daria mentioned above, it's «на Аляске» because, at first, Alaska is perceived as an area not as a state. To be more specific and refer to a state, use «в штате Аляска»).

Answer (score 1):

Не требует, но напрашивается. Аляска, как и Гаваи не в составе континентальных штатов.

Comment: Usage of *на Аляске* and *на Гавайях* predates the statehood of both states. California was once a non-contiguous state as well, still Russian has never had *на Калифорнии*.

Comment: California may not have been contiguous but it was continental.

Comment: technically, Alaska is continental too. But my point is that the usage of the preposition is not about state incorporation subtleties.

Comment: still, you dont say `на Пуэрто-Рико`, but `в Пуэрто-Рико`, even though its an island.

Answer (score 1):

Как уже пояснили, есть определённые правила, основанные на географическом "происхождении" тех или иных регионов. На острове - значит "на Гавайях", на территории - значит, "на Урале", "на Камчатке", "на Аляске". Однако - "в Сибири". Потому что есть правила, а есть традиции произношения, так же как в английском, например, неправильные формы глаголов. "На Украине" тоже говорят потому, что это изначально была территория, включающая в себя множество совершенно различных областей, а не одно цельное этнически и исторически образование. Исторически прижилось "на", а то, что теперь это страна, никого не заставит менять привычное произношение.

Ещё про исторически прижившееся.
Например, город Paris - это Париж, а не "Пари", "Парис" или "Пэрис". А вот Paris Hilton - это уже Пэрис.

Одного принципа, по которому можно всё понять, нет, нужно просто много практики. Трудно быть иностранным шпионом в России, в общем.

Comment: Неправильные формы глаголов - это немного другое. Раньше было несколько видов изменения глаголов (даже сейчас неправильные глаголы можно разделить на несколько групп), просто форма -ed стала вытеснять (и продолжает вытеснять) другие.

Comment: Ну другое, а проблема одна - чёткого правила на все случаи нет, нужно что-то просто запомнить.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the more peculiar paradoxes of the Russian language, and something a lot of Russians question and laugh at as well.

```
В Бруклине, В Квинсе, В Бронксе - На Манхеттене, На Стэйтэн-Айланде
В России - На Украине
```

etc.

Comment: Manhattan and Staten Island are, well, islands, so *на* is justified here.

Answer (score 0):

*Возможно* на выбор предлога наряду с классификацией объекта ("на" - на поверхности чего-либо, на острове/полуострове, "в" - внутри чего-либо, внутри города, административной единицы или государства), также влияет фонетический состав слова.

Если в слове доминируют "а", "у" -- то комфортнее говорить "на" (на Урале, на Аляске). Если "и", "е", "о" -- то комфортнее говорить "в" (в Сибири, в степи).

P.S.
Исключение: говорят "на континенте", но "в Азии", "в Америке", "в Африке", "в Антарктиде", "в Европе".